# How to manually degrade stream quality for debugging purposes?

Tags: webrtc, opentok

I am trying to test that a certain event (`videoDisableWarning`) from OpenTok subscriber gets triggered: https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Subscriber.html

For this, I need to degrade "the quality of the stream". I can't find a way to do so with chrome dev tools. How would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an application like [NetLimiter](https://www.netlimiter.com/) to manually throttle your browser network speed.

Answer (score 0):

Throttling the browser should work for you. Just throttle it into a very slow speed (2G?). I'm trying to do the same, but can't find a way to automate it in Jest or a script. Opened a Playwright feature suggestion ticket to see if we can get it there. Feel free to jump in and +1 it to see if we can improve stream testing in libraries.